# Absolute difference of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a sample data below, how do i get the absolute difference of the values under the 'deaths/births' columns for the two cities and have the results show under the 'difference' column.

The dates match up, is there a way i can use a conditional statement? Or can i use .loc so that i can subtract the values in the 'deaths/births_Houston' column from rows 0-4 with the values in the 'death/births_Austin' from rows 5-9.

So far i have used these codes to calculate the 'death/births' columns:
`data.loc[0:4,'deaths/births_Houston']=np.round(data.loc[0:4,'deaths']/data.loc[0:4,'births']*100,3)`
`data.loc[5:9,'deaths/births_Austin']=np.round(data.loc[5:9,'deaths']/data.loc[5:9,'births']*100,3)`

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: `df["Difference"] = abs(df["Deaths"] - df["Births"])`

Comment: but thats only subtracting the values under 'deaths' and 'births' column. how would i do it for the values under 'deaths/births' columns?

Comment: You might need to merge them into separate columns - having them in alternating coords is simply too awkward. EDIT: what I mean by this is to have a col for H deaths and births and others for A deaths and births, etc. You could probably search up how to do that. From there you can replace the NaN then take the difference using a modified version of the thing I gave above.